# How to write this meaning in a MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, function, range

How to write this meaning in a MySQL query?

```
where ((location/'$location'<2) and (location/'$location'>=1))
```

Comment: What's wrong with that? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: @Steven: It's not fair to those who answered, to change the criteria after they've answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
where location/'$location' between 1 and 2
```

**Edit**: Since it should only match those that are precisely 2, then this should work:

```
where location div '$location' = 2
```

Comment: The range is [1,2) location and $location are integers.

Comment: So basically range is 2. Period. Ergo "where location/'$location' == 2" ?

Comment: You can edit your answer to add content - the edit link is to the right of the voting, between link and flag.

Comment: fwiw, `==` is not an operator in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you want floating-point division, that should be fine, but if you want integer division:

```
WHERE location DIV '$location' IN (1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have to know a bit more about your database but are you trying to select something such as:

```
select location from -- some table 
where ((location/'$location'<2) and (location/'$location'>=0))
```